# Webpack cannot create working module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';


class NotWorking extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.info('notworking');
        return <div>js sucks</div>;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    NotWorking
};
```

Build it with:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/NotWorking.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'notworking.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

The idea is to have this as an npm module; so I want to include the build in another project (hopefully via node_modules then, for now I just require it as follows):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import NotWorking from './../build/notworking.js';


class MustWork extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.info('mustwork');
        return <div>
            must work
            <NotWorking />
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MustWork />, document.getElementById('kitchen_sink'));
```

I build it with an exact same webpack config as above, except the filename changes.

I get this error when using it:

[image]

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `MustWork`.

Which means the notworking file is not building correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of making it a reusable library the `library` attribute needs to be specified in the webpack output:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'smallgrid.js',
    library: 'SmallGrid',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    externals: {
        react: 'react',
        lodash: 'lodash'
    }
},
```

Also, the `libraryTarget` needed to be set to `umd`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are exporting an object but it is empty. You may want to create a key and assign the component to it, or just export the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';


class NotWorking extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.info('notworking');
        return <div>js sucks</div>;
    }
}

module.exports default {NotWorking: NotWorking};
```

**EDIT**
I think that your code should work. Is just that i didn't saw that syntax before. On [MDN documentation it is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) as you are doing it but the import is:

```
import {NotWorking} from './../build/notworking.js';
```

Comment: Why does it also not work when using `export default class NotWorking`?

Comment: I believe that the syntax inline on the definition is `export class ...`  if you want [to use the default keyword you might want to omit the name](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). `export default class {}`

Comment: Why are you importing the build version? you should import the development version of the file

Comment: Like I said I want to make an npm library; which must be build. This is just a simplified version of the problem I'm having. The import `NotWorking` is `undefined` it seems. not sure why nothing is working

Comment: When I use `export default class extends React.Component {` it is an empty object `{ }`

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie have a look at [this babel plugin](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports), it might be what you are looking for